# C++: IF was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++

I am trying to make an `if else` statement but every time I type in the code, errors come up. One of them says `IF was not declared in this scope` and I have no idea how to declare it and it all. It also says that there is no `}` before my else statement but there clearly is; please help.

Here Is The Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string UserInput;

    cin >> UserInput;

    int x;
    x = 1;

    If (UserInput = x);
    {
        cout << "Type A Word and Press enter";
    }
    else
    {
        Cout << "NOT A USESBLE NUMBER";
    }

    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(255, '\n');
    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wow, four mistakes in just `If (UserInput = x);`. That might be a record.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz LOL, Better than my hours to find mistake many years ago of if(x==100,000)

Comment: Can you please choose a best answer by clicking on the check mark next to it? It helps a lot!

Answer (score 12):

```
If (UserInput = x);
```

Keywords, just like variables in C++ are case-sensitive, meaning that they are to be spelled and have the same case every time you write it. In your code, your `IF` is coming up as undeclared/undefined because the compiler thinks you're using it as a variable or  function that hasn't been defined yet. An if statement is to be written in lowercase. So the result should be this:

```
if (UserInput = x);
```

But we're not done yet. We still have a few more problems here. The single equal sign in the if statement is interpreted as an assignment (It doesn't throw an error because technically it's correct syntax, but many people make this mistake by using a single equal sign instead of the double equal sign). The correct syntax would be the double equal sign if you are intending to compare instead of assign.

```
if (UserInput == x);
```

Note: This code is still incorrect because you are comparing a string to a number. When you do `cin >> UserInput`, the user's text will be converted to a string for the variable `UserInput` so it can never be an integer like `x` to which the number 1 is assigned. In other words this `if` will fail every time on the basis that a string is not an integer. Instead, we should use `if (UserInput == "1")` to compare it to a 1 as a string literal.

```
if (UserInput == "1");
```

That semi-colon at the end shouldn't be there. This is not the end of a statement, just the end of the line. The if statement still needs either one line of code following it (optionally, if the brackets are omitted), or the two curly brackets encasing multiple lines of code.

```
if (UserInput == "1")
{
    /* ... */

    Cout >> "NOT A USESBLE NUMBER";
}
```

`Cout` should be completely lowercase since it was defined in lowercase.

After looking over your code this is what I think you intended it to be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string UserInput;

    cin >> UserInput;

    if (UserInput == "1") {
        cout << "Type A Word and Press enter";
    }
    else {
        cout << "NOT A USESBLE NUMBER";
    }

    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(255, '\n');
    cin.get();

    // "return 0" is implicit.
}
```

Comment: Nice answer - lots of info for the OP

Comment: What is a USESBLE NUMBER, anyway?

Comment: @FredOverflow Honestly, I don't have a clue. lol

Answer (score 7):

Your code  is incorrect first you are using a capital I and 2nd you have a semicolon at then end of the line and 3rd equality has 2 equals signs

```
int x;
x=1;
If (UserInput = x);
```

Should be

```
std::string x("1");
if (UserInput == x)
```

Comment: You should probably explain why this is correct as opposed to his code.

Comment: @David - What do you suggest I add?

Comment: -1 you are comparing against string....not a good practice....

Comment: I am not comparing against anything ;-) but good point will edit

Comment: @AdrianCornish:- You tried compiling this code???? I really doubt it will ever compile for such faulty comparison.I dont think string has some operator overload for == .. :)

Comment: When you have read the C++ standard 23.3 - why dont you ask me that question again

Comment: thanks but now it says that there is an                                invalid non version from 'char' to 'const char*'                 and                  initializing argument 1 of 'std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traitl,        _Alloc>::basic_string(const _cha

Comment: @user1610489 Let me know the exact code and the whole compiler error and I can help you more

Comment: @Anonymous String has compare, you just need to do this str1.compare(str2) == 0.

Comment: AFAIK the first line shouldn't compile as std::string has no constructor (let alone implicit) taking a character. @user1610489, That would be your problem, as the `const char *` it needs is easily obtained from `"1"`.

Comment: @chris Quite correct - edited to reflect. Thanks for finding my error

Comment: @chris If that was you for the upvote - lots of thanks - You made me hit 4K :-)

Answer (score 3):

**if** needs to be lower case in C.

Comment: You missed the extra semicolon :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
std::string x='1';
if (UserInput==x)
{
  cout << "Type A Word and Press enter";
} else
{
    cout << "NOT A USESBLE NUMBER";//Cout should be cout
}
```

Comment: @AdrianCornish:- Real bad way to treat newbies ;)

Comment: Why - I explained why I downvoted their answer and if they edit it I will upvote again. Better than a cowardly downvote with no explanation? :-)

Comment: Why are we checking if the first character is a control-A?

Comment: AFAIK the first line shouldn't compile as `std::string` has no constructor (let alone implicit) taking a character.